# Naming Conventions in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, file-geodatabase, feature-class, route

I am new to using ModelBuilder, however, I have created a model to create "straight lines" that represent multiple stream condition monitoring. I have multiple gdbs, and within, multiple feature classes for each date a stream was monitored. The set naming convention when creating these straight lines (routes essentially) manually are as follows "5 digit DEP code_Date" for example "12345_20160404" Is there a way for me to set naming conventions in ModelBuilder? I am not opposed to using python.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in the current date, then the [Calculate Value](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/calculate-value.htm) tool could be of use, along with some python.  Below is the code that would return the current date as a string.  In the Expression box, put this:  getdate()
In the code block, put the following:

```py
def getdate():
  import datetime
  now = datetime.datetime.now()
  current_date = str(now)[:10].replace('-','')
  return current_date
```

It will return a date in year/month/day, such as "20160421".
Right click on "Output Value" of this tool and select "Rename".  Type in "CurrentDate".  Now, wherever you name your output files, use "*%CurrentDate%" on the end of the name.  So if your DEP code is "12345", then "12345*%CurrentDate%" goes into the output file name.  This is called [Inline Variable Substitution](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/inline-variable-substitution.htm).

**Note that you may not be able to name your output file starting with a number. Would recommend putting a character on the front end.**

For your codes, I'm not sure how you get those or if you have more than one, so give us more info if you want that automated also.

Comment: Unfortunately, the current date will not work. The field techs get back to the office after I am gone, and the data must be downloaded and QAQC'd the next day. Plus, these maps are not pressing so I do them once a week. Another unfortunate thing are the naming codes. The 5 digit code is the stream name given by the DEP. The only other way to name them would be the literal name that you would typically see on a map which would be a ridiculous amount of characters.

Comment: My next thought would be to try and name the output feature classes from fields in the attribute table. My attribute table contains the DEP name codes, as well as the date the streams were monitored. Do you think that is a possibility?

Comment: Would all rows in the feature class have the same DEP code and the same date in the date field?

Comment: No. I have one excel table per week (April wk 1, wk 2, etc) with multiple tabs that represent days of the week. On any given day, 5+ streams are monitored therefore there are 5+ DEP codes in each tab/table.

Comment: I'm getting confused on when you create a feature class.    It might help to throw in a screen shot

Comment: I create a new feature class by exporting the event data that is created from "adding route events" (File> Add data> Add Route Event ... add your info to the window that appears and an event appears in your TOC). In model builder, a new event is created under the tool "make route event layer" So essentially, I need to export the events into feature classes. I'm not sure how to link a picture, or else  I would.